# Externally call function inside this.each(function(){}) from a jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
(function( $ ){

$.fn.foo = function(params) {

    params = $.extend( {
        on: false
    }, params);

    this.each(function(){
        if(params.on) {
            function alertDate(){
                alert('FOO BAR!!!');
            }
        }
    });
};
})( jQuery );
```

How can i access the "alertDate()" function from out of the script?

if i use:

```
$('#test').foo()
```

will give-me access for the function, ok, everything fine, i will gain access to function "alertDate()" internally at this.each(function(){}).

I want to access the function "alertDate()" externally by something like:

```
$('#text').foo({on: 'true'}).each().alertDate();
```

How can i do this?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the poor english

Comment: .fn.foo ?? is there a typo in there?

Comment: that's not a normal design pattern for a jQuery plugin - can you perhaps explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Alnitak, i have a code with 650+ lines, i just recreated my issue for someone understand what i want to access. I want to access functions from `this.each(function(){})`

Comment: WAAAAAA. Uh uh, there are lots of things to do with this. There are many things to change until your code will be working the way you expect, and there are many conventions you are breaking with the way you are trying to call your function. I will feel glad if you want to discuss this slowly on the chat room, but I don't know how to do that :( does anyone know haw to do that? xD

Comment: @Áxel, my code work as well. As i said. I don't wrote 650+ lines of non working code. I've follow the jquery official documentation about plugin creation and my plugin work's as a charm. The example i've post in the question, i'm have to say (again), is one example of problem i want to solve. I want to access a function inside the `THIS.EACH(FUNCTION(){})`. Anyway, thanks for all your observations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would handle it, so that your `alertDate()` function can be used both internally and externally:

```
$.fn.foo = function(params) {
    params = $.extend( {
        on: false
    }, params);

    this.alertDate = function(){
        alert("FOO BAR!!!");
    }

    this.each(function(){
        if(params.on) {
            this.alertDate();
        }
    });

    return this; 
};

//Externally the alertDate function could be called as:
$("test").foo().alertDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, but this is not how plugins normally work.

```
$.fn.foo = function() {
    function bar() { 
        alert("bar");
    } 
    this.bar = bar; 
    return this; 
};

$("a").foo().bar();
```